# Why does my JS function not return any results in Chrome Dev Console?

Tags: javascript, html, function

My function compPlay() does not return any results in console. I have the function written to what I believe is correct as far as syntax goes and proper use of "Math random" and "Math" floor. Please help me.

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en-us">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Rock Paper Scissor Game</title>
        <!-- CSS, STYLESHEET -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style2.css">
        <!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- JQUERY, 3.2.1 -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">

            function compPlay {
                const choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
                return choices([Math.floor(Math.random() * choice.length)];
            }
```

[image]

Comment: Missing parenthesis `function compPlay () {`

Answer (score 1):

A `script` tag may contain either `src` attribute or code defined inside. If it has both the code inside is ignored. After correcting that, you will see all the syntax errors your code has.

```js
console.log(compPlay());
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function compPlay() {
    const choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
    return choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your *compPlay* function is not contained between *script* tags.
Use this and your function should work fine on the browser console.

```html
    <script>
    function compPlay() {
     const choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
     return choices([Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)] );
    }
    </script>
```

Futhermore, note the **()** added after *compPlay*

Comment: Furthermore, note the erroneous "(" after `return choices` and missing "s" in `choice.length`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, comPlay is not defined as a method.

Instead of this:

```
function compPlay {
            const choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
            return choices([Math.floor(Math.random() * choice.length)];
        }
```

Try this:

```
function compPlay() {
    const choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
    return choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choice.length)];
}
```

Comment: `choices` is not a function

Comment: @Igor apologies mate. Thanks for correcting me.